# Cannot display Object

Tags: html, angular, typescript, firebase, object

I get the following object from Firebase. I save this object in a variable called `articleDetails`.

`Console.log(this.articleDetails)` displays the retrieved object as follows:

[image]

In .ts file, this object is initialized as:

```
export class ArticlePage {
public articleDetails = {};
...
}
```

In HTML of the same .ts file, I use:

```
<p> {{ articleDetails?.bigTitle }} </p>
```

However, it doesn't show anything on the screen!

I wonder if this error is because this object has a key - the key of the object is 3, for example. Where am I making a mistake?

Comment: Maybe you could provide with more details on how you're retrieving the articles, and how are you using them, in order to give a more useful answer :)

Comment: `Object.key()` ?

Answer (score 1):

You're intuition is correct, you're getting something like a list of Articles, so you need to look by key. For this sample data, this would work:

```
<p> {{ articleDetails['3'].bigTitle }} </p>
```

Usually this is done in a [loop](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf):

```
<li *ngFor="let item of articleDetails">
    <p> {{ item.bigTitle }} </p>
</li>
```